# Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that does UNION ALL for about 5000 select statements. When i run this i get this error

```
Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Based on similar other questions i have changed the value in my `my.ini` file and restarted the server. I have set the value to 1GB which is the max that mysql accepts. I can see the new value of 1GB being picked up by the server. I can check it by running this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

I still continue to get this error. I saved the actual SQL statement to a text file and its only 4.4mb.

What can i do to fix this.

**Example Select Statement**: There are about 5000 of these. The only thing that changes is the `id`

```
SELECT 
  SUM(postpay_GA + prepay_ga) AS GA,
  CAST(SUM(EDGE_NUM) / SUM(EDGE_DEN) AS DECIMAL (10, 4)) * 100 AS EDGE,
  SUM(ACC_REV) / SUM(ATR_D) AS ARD,
  (CAST(SUM(promot) AS DECIMAL (10, 4)) / SUM(surv) - CAST(SUM(DETRAC) AS DECIMAL (10, 4)) / SUM(surv)) * 100 AS NPS,
  SUM(Renew) AS GR 
FROM
  store_dashboard_data_dly 
WHERE ACTIVITY_MTH BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30' 
  AND region_cd = **'NE'** 
  AND logic = 'eis' 
UNION
ALL 
SELECT 
  SUM(quota * (metric_id = 1)),
  AVG(NULLIF(quota * (metric_id = 7), 0)),
  AVG(NULLIF(quota * (metric_id = 10), 0)),
  AVG(NULLIF(quota * (metric_id = 14), 0)),
  SUM(quota * (metric_id = 2)) 
FROM
  rop_budget 
WHERE id = **'NE'** 
  AND start_date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30'
```

Comment: did you change BOTH the server and client's max_allowed_packets? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: my client is an JAVA application. Also i am testing it in SQLYog. How would i set this in those 2 enviroments?

Comment: Why would a query that unions 5000 select statements be valid?  Odds are this can be rewritten unless you have an extremely poorly designed database.

Comment: I am running some backend job on a DB. Speed is not critical. I have run half the query and it takes about a minute. Taking 2 minutes for the full statement is fine in terms of performance for me. PLus the job happens at night when no one cares about speed. Is there a way to merge result Sets?

Comment: Can you give a small example with lets say 5 selects, I can honestly say I have never heard of a union query with thousands of select statements. There has to be some way to reduce the number of queries.

Comment: @Lennart see updated question for the select statement

Comment: How many distinct tables are you selecting from?

Comment: @Lennart I am selecting from 2 distinct tables

Comment: The problem is not in the *statement*, it is likely in how the results are processed. Check with EXPLAIN. I had begun an answer before noticing @Laurence 's which was the same [actually, with more efficient sorting]. I upvote his answer and strongly suggest you to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get all the results in a simpler way by using `group by`

```
select
    x.ga,
    x.edge,
    x.ard,
    x.nps,
    x.gr
from (
    select
        d.region_cd,
        sum(d.postpay_ga + d.prepay_ga) as ga,
        cast(sum(d.edge_num) / sum(d.edge_den) as decimal(10, 4)) * 100 as edge,
        sum(d.acc_rev) / sum(d.atr_d) as ard,
        (cast(sum(d.promot) as decimal(10, 4)) / sum(d.surv) 
          - cast(sum(d.detrac) as decimal(10, 4)) / sum(d.surv)) * 100 as nps,
        sum(d.Renew) as gr,
        1 as ord
    from
        store_dashboard_data_dly as d
    where
        d.activity_mth between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-30' and
        d.region_cd in ('NE', 'R2', 'R3', ...) and
        d.logic = 'eis'
    group by
        d.region_cd
    union all
    select
        id,
        sum(quota * (metric_id = 1)),
        avg(nullif(quota * (metric_id = 7), 0)),
        avg(nullif(quota * (metric_id = 10), 0)),
        avg(nullif(quota * (metric_id = 14), 0)),
        sum(quota * (metric_id = 2)),
        2
    from
        rop_budget 
    where
        id in ('NE', 'R2', 'R3', ...) and
        start_date between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-30'
) x
order by
    x.id,
    x.ord
```

If you want the results to be ordered in the same order you defined the queries in, then you could create a temporary table with `region_cd, sequence_no`. Insert the region/sequence then use it to join on tthe report tables.